# How to erase just some bytes of Flash Memory?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, bootloader, microchip

My [PIC18F87J11](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778b.pdf) only erases 1024 bytes at a time. **Is there away to force it to only erase 2 bytes or more at a time?**

I am making a Bootloader and sometimes only one line of the HEX file (16 bytes) changes for the application program, so I want to replace that line in memory with the new 16 bytes only . If I try to erase those 16 bytes, automatically 1024 bytes get erased too. Then I am forced to re-write them which takes some time and reduce the speed of the Bootloader.

**Is there an alternative way of erasing something from flash memory without erasing 1024 byes?** Hopefully there is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot erase less than the "erase block size" of the underlying memory implementation.  If that is 1024 bytes on your device (something you can verify) then that is the smallest size you can erase.

You may be able to copy the entire block to RAM (if available), modify only the necessary portions, erase the flash block, and then write it back, avoiding the need to re-upload unchanged portions from an *external* source.

In many of these technologies, there is also a direction you can write in without erasing - for example, the memory may permit changing a "1" to a "0", but only an erase cycle can change a "0" back to a "1".  Depending on your precise needs, you may be able to design a scheme which takes advantage of this.

Comment: Yea, I noticed if the registers I am trying to write to are empty, I can write to them without erasing anything, and even replace them later without erasing them at all. However, if those registers had something in there initially, like after programming the PIC, I can only replace them once. After that I need to erase the entire block to be able to write something different. Any more suggestions ?

Comment: Thats it, "erasing flash" is only done in blocks or pages, all the bits in that page are set one way.  "Writing flash" is a one way process of some of the bits being changed from the erase state to non-erased.  So to erase some bits requires making a copy, erasing the page, and writing the copy plus changes back, there are no other options.  That is how eeprom and flash have worked traditionally, if new technologies come out then well, the story may change some day

Comment: Well, I appreciate both of you guys answers, especially for given me alternatives on how to still achieve what I want just in a different way. For now, I will just copy the contents of the block to ram before erasing, but hopefully this process isn't going to be too slow.

Comment: This is not normally a problem for bootloader type applications but you need to be aware that erasing and programming the flash memory cell is a destructive process for which there is a physical maximum number of cycles after which the memory may fail.  In the data sheet for your device the specified minimum number of erase cycles that the flash will survive is 1000 with a device typically surviving 10000 cycles before failing.